# draw line with jquery between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

how can I draw line between two div's with jquery library or simple javascript?

I have various div's boxes on page with there id's

## id1 #id2 #id3 #id4 and #id5 and so on...

what I wants if I click on #div1 and drag it to #div2 It will make an arrow line between #div1 and #div2 pointing to 2, And somehow save this connection details. Also i can attach #div1 to other div's and it save that connection details as well.

(I am using jquery UI if that matters).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i found https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb to solve this issue..

Comment: Brilliant!  Exactly what the doctor ordered!