# HTML5 pathfinding

Tags: html, 3d, path-finding

Is it possible to create a pathfinding feature using HTML5 only. I am looking for something very simple like connecting two points (not in a straight line) with dotted line. The ultimate  result will be a pathfinding in a 3d context but for now i'll stick to something simple and will build on that unless you know a way to do the 3d pathfinding.

Thank you

Comment: No JS , no CSS ? only HTML5 ? - impossible. With JS - it becomes just a regular path-finding task. Use [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm)

Comment: when i said HTML5 i meant no flash or anything like that...of course i am going to use css and jquery...can you point me to the right direction as to how to achieve this using the combination of the three

Comment: [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-draggable-divs) older [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707127/draw-line-with-jquery-between-two-divs) recommend [jSplumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of A* implementations in javascript an MIT licensed A* implementation is here: http://briangrinstead.com

Comment: yeah sorry, I made it when working for a company that went in a different direction and took down the demo.